Is there a way to prove whether a connection used the MultiSubnetFailover argument?
I know that consulting sys.dm_exec_connections can show whether a connection is using an AOAG listener or was made directly to the instance. And I know that if a connection is successful that it was successful (it seems pretty obvious). However, I've got an internal customer who wants me to prove wether a session used the MultiSubnetFailover argument in its connection string. Is there any way to do this via the various system tables, DMVs, etc? I don't have access to the application server, so any proof must be found within SQL Server itself.

The fact that the TDS protocol doesn't allow for this argument to be sent as part of the connection process seems to end the debate (at least from my side). Hopefully my customer realizes as much.
